# Azure container instance still creating when using docker compose

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I am trying to deploy my containerized application to azure using docker compose aci context. For this I am following this tutorial: tutorial-docker-compose

It works fine, when I use a simple docker compose definition with only 3 services. See below the docker-compose.yaml that works:

```yaml
 version: "3"
    
 services:
   node1:
     build:
       context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-1.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8881
     ports:
       - 8881
     networks:
       local:
         ipv4_address: 172.28.1.101
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node2:
     build:
       context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-2.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8882
     ports:
       - 8882
     networks:
       local:
         ipv4_address: 172.28.1.102
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node3:
     build:
       context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-3.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8883
     ports:
       - 8883
     networks:
       local:
         ipv4_address: 172.28.1.103
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
    
 networks:
   local:
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.1.0/24
          gateway: 172.28.1.1
```

The problem is when I try to increase the number of services, the containers still creating and I have the following error.

```bash
$ docker compose --verbose -f .\nodes-123.docker-compose.yaml up
 level=debug msg="Up on project with name \"lab01-blockchain\""
 [+] Running 1/7
  - Group lab01-blockchain  Created                                                                                                                                                    7.7s 
  - node1                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s
  - node2                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s 
  - node3                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s 
  - node4                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s 
  - node5                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s 
  - node6                   Creating                                                                                                                                                 900.0s 
 Future#WaitForCompletion: context has been cancelled: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded
```

The docker-compose.yaml with 6 services is the following:

```yaml
version: "3"
    
 services:
   node1:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-1.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8881
     ports:
       - 8881
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.101
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node2:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-2.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8882
     ports:
       - 8882
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.102
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node3:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-3.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8883
     ports:
       - 8883
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.103
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node4:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-3.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8884
     ports:
       - 8884
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.104
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node5:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-3.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8885
     ports:
       - 8885
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.105
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   node6:
     # build:
     #   context: server
     image: ***.azurecr.io/node-server
     command: ./server -config config/cloud-neighbour-3.yaml -socket-address 0.0.0.0 -socket-port 8886
     ports:
       - 8886
     # networks:
     #   local:
     #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.106
     deploy:
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
         reservations:
           cpus: '0.50'
           memory: 1G
   # client:
   #   image: ***.azurecr.io/client
   #   command: ./client
   #   networks:
   #     local:
   #       ipv4_address: 172.28.1.200
   #   deploy:
   #     resources:
   #       limits:
   #         cpus: '0.50'
   #         memory: 1G
    
 # networks:
 #   local:
 #     driver: bridge
 #     ipam:
 #      config:
 #        - subnet: 172.28.1.0/24
 #          gateway: 172.28.1.1
```

I tried to remove the network on container to see if it is better, but not.
Please note, that I am using deploy.resources.limits on my docker-compose.yaml file to not exceed quota defined by Azure (4 CPU, 16G RAM).
Note alse, that I use the flag --verbose when using docker compose but it seems that I didn't have more logging..

Regards

Comment: Hi @Bruno MC , Can you try using the Version 3.4 instead and share the results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9934379/bruno-mc please try using version 3.4 instead and share the results.